# lua tried to run function with variable artuments

Tags: lua

This is a lua question:

```
fuction nameit(...)
    for i =1, select('#, ...) do
        local arg = select(i, ...)  -- get i-th parameter
        print( arg )
    end
end

nameit('apple','banana','orange')
```

I got this error:
lua  '=' expected near 'nameit'

Comment: Did you, by chance, get this error in the REPL after trying to redefine the function? Perhaps with the first error being, "stdin:2: unfinished string near ''#, ...) do'"?

Comment: Lua 5.2 issues a better error message: `syntax error near 'nameit'`.

Answer (score 3):

You have misspelt `function`in the first line.

Comment: ...and haven't closed string after `'#`